# Cant stop FortiClient vpn from starting on startup

Tags: boot, vpn, startup, schedule

I'm using **FortiClient** for VPN purposes only and don't need it running any other time. I can't get disabled from starting on startup. How to disable auto-launching of FortClient on startup?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can do it using these commands with sudo privilege:

**To shutdown FortiClient:**

```
systemctl stop forticlient-scheduler
```

**To disable the auto start at the next boot:**

```
systemctl disable forticlient-scheduler
```

Edit: As mentioned by others, for the newer versions `forticlient-scheduler` is changed to `forticlient`

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me.

Comment: Thanks! Using forticlient 7, it's just "forticlient" :)

Comment: Like @QuentiumYT mentioned, the command is now `systemctl disable forticlient`

Answer (score 4):

This took me quite a bit to find, after running `systemctl disable forticlient` the fortytraylauncher was still autostarting. I still had to remove the file `/etc/xdg/autostart/Fortitray.desktop`. If yours is in a different location, try finding it at one of the paths from `$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS/autostart`.